# How do I input a password from a makefile or system( ) call?

Tags: c, makefile, server, passwords, scp

I'm working on a C project that makes connections to remote servers. Commonly, this involves using some small terminal macros I've added to my makefile to scp an executable to that remote server. While convenient, the only part of this I've not been able to readily streamline is the part where I need to enter the password.

Additionally, in my code, I'm already using system() calls to accomplish some minor terminal commands (like sort). I'd ALSO like to be able to enter a password if necessary here. For instance, if I wanted to build a string in my code to scp a local file to my remote server, it'd be really nice to have my code pull (and use) a password from somewhere so it can actually access that server.

Does anyone a little more experienced with Make know a way to build passwords into a makefile and/or a system() call in C? Bonus points if I can do it without any third-party software/libraries. I'm trying to keep this as self-contained as possible.

Edit: In reading responses, it's looking like the best strategy is to establish a preexisting ssh key relationship with the server to avoid the login process via something more secure. More work up front for less work in the future, by the sound of it, with additional security.

Thanks for the suggestions, all.

Comment: SCP uses SSH for authentication. "SCP without password" and "SSH without password" should yield thousands of answers, but in short: you need to add you public key to the remote server user's `authorized_keys`. Easy to research!

Comment: Any reason you can't use ssh keys to avoid using passwords?

Comment: Note also that using `ssh` without a password with its keys is significantly **more** secure than using a password with your application.  Getting right to the point bluntly, anyone who doesn't agree literally doesn't know what they're talking about.  Especially for things like automated processes - how do you propose storing your password securely?

Comment: The "work upfront" is calling `ssh-copy-id user@servername` exactly once locally, and typing in your password once. It's not really much "work".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to *not* use a password. SSH, and thus SCP, has, among many many others, public key authentication, which is described all over the internet. Use that.

Generally, the problem you're trying to solve is called *secret management*, and the takeaway is that your authentication tokens (passwords, public keys, API keys…) should not be owned by your application software, but by something instructing the authenticating layer. In other words, the way forward really *is* that you enable SSH to connect on its own without you entering a password by choosing something that happens to *not* be an interactive authentication method. So, using a password here is less elegant than just using the generally favorable method of using a public key to authenticate with your server.

Passing passwords as command line option is generally a bad idea – that leaks these passwords into things like process listings, potentially log entries and so on. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Running `ssh-keygen` to create the keys. Then, adding/appending the local system's (e.g) `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to the remote's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file *is* the best way to go.

But, I had remote systems to access without passwords but the file was *not* installed on the remote (needing `ssh-keygen` to be run on the remote). Or, the remote `.ssh/authorized_keys` files did *not* have the public key from my local system in it.

I wanted a one-time automated/unattended script to add it. A chicken-and-the-egg problem.

I found [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass)

It will work like `ssh` and provide the password (similar to what `expect` does).

I installed it *once* on the local system.

Using this, the script would:

1. run `ssh-keygen` on the remote [if necessary]
2. Append the local `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public key file to the remote's `.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. Copy back the remote's `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to the local system's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file [if desired]

Then, `ssh` etc. worked *without* any passwords.

---

**UPDATE:**

> `ssh_copy_id` is your fried, too.

I had forgotten about that. But, when I was doing this, I had more complex requirements.

The aforementioned script would merge/combine all the public keys and update all the `authorized_keys` files on all the systems. This would be repeated anytime any new system was added to the mix.

> you never need to run ssh-keygen on a remote host, especially not to generate an authorized_keys file. –
> Marcus Müller

I think that was inferred but not implied as a requirement [particularly in context]. I hope the answer wasn't -1 for that.

Note that (1) `ssh-keygen` is needed for (3) copy back the public key.

Ironically, one of the tutorial pages for `ssh-copy-id` says run `ssh-keygen` first ...

It's been my exerience when setting up certain types of systems/clusters (e.g. a development host/PC and several remote/target/test ones), if one wants to do local-to-remote actions, invariably one wants to do:

1. remote-to-local actions -- (e.g.) I'm ssh'ed into a remote system and want to do `rcp` back to the development system.
2. The remote system needs to do a `git clone/pull` from [and, sometimes, `git push` to] the local git server.
3. remote-to-remote -- copying/streaming data between target systems.

This requires that each system have a private/public key pair and all systems have an  `authorized_keys` file that has the public keys of all the other systems.

When I've *not* set up the systems that way it usually comes back to haunt me [usually late at night when I'm tired]. So, I just [axiomatically] set it up that way at the outset.

One of the reasons that I developed the script in the first place. Also, since we didn't want to have to maintain a fork of a given system/distro installer for production systems, we would:

1. Use the stock/standard distro installer CD/USB
2. Use the script to add the extra/custom config, S/W, drivers, etc.

Comment: `ssh_copy_id` is your fried, too. you **never** need to run ssh-keygen on a remote host, especially not to generate an `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think there _are_ reasons. I've updated my answer with more explanation.

Comment: interesting angle. It seems you want a reverse shell, not just a remote shell. There's tricks you can do to enable that without adding a public key of a remote server locally, if you're going to open a connection in the "forward" direction first (essentially, you can use the remote server as JumpHost, and use your own local public key to log in to your local ssh); anyways, yep, this is much nicer (and my -1 might have been a bit negative, so reverted that)